# Как реализовать вывод, чтобы каждые 2 значения обворачивались в еще один div

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день! Имеется вот такой код в наличии:

```
<?php

include ('engine/api/api.class.php'); // подключаем api
$table = 'dle_post';  // название таблицы
$fields  = 'xfields'; // нужные поля, * - все поля
$where = 'approve=1'; // условия выборки
$multirow = 1; // забирать ли один ряд или несколько
$start = 0; // начальное значение выборки
$limit = 0; // количество записей для выборки, 0 - выбрать все
$xfield = 'years'; ///ИМЯ ДОП ПОЛЯ ДЛЯ ВЫВОДА
$time = '14000'; //время жизни кеша

function declOfNum($num, $titles) {
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);

    return $num . " " . $titles[($num % 100 > 4 && $num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($num % 10, 5)]]; //склоняем слова
}

$xfields = $dle_api->load_from_cache ($fields, $time, $xfields); //берем наш кеш, если есть конечно ))
if( !$xfields ) { //проверяем взяли ли мы кеш и если не взяли, то делаем запрос
    $xfields = $dle_api->load_table ($table,$fields,$where,$multirow,$start,$limit); //делаем запрос к бд
    $dle_api->save_to_cache ( xfields, $xfields); //сохраняем в кеш
    }

$stack = array(); //создаем пустой массив
foreach($xfields as $value){  // перебор значений массива
    if($value[xfields]){ //проверяем есть ли элемент в массиве

        $row = xfieldsdataload($value[xfields]); //получаем нужное нам доп поле
        if($row[$xfield]){ //проверяем есть ли значение

            $rowdata = explode( ",", $row[$xfield]); //разбиваем наше значение на массив
            foreach($rowdata as $value){    //перебираем значения массива
                if($value){                    //проверяем есть ли значение
                    $value = trim($value);    //убираем пробелы
                    array_push($stack, $value); //добавляем в конец массива полученное значение
                    arsort($stack, SORT_NUMERIC);         //сортировка в обратном порядке
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
$stack = array_count_values($stack); //считаем повторы и избавляемся от повторных значений
foreach($stack as $key => $count){  //выводим окончательный вариант
    echo "<div class='blok'>"; //открываем див
    echo "<a href=/" . $xfield . "/";  //открываем ссылку
    echo $key; //подставляем значение для поиска
    echo ">";
    echo $key; //имя ссылки
    echo "</a>"; //закрываем ссылку
    echo "<br><span>";  //открываем спан
    echo declOfNum($count, array('год', 'года', 'годов'));//кол-во повторов со склонением
    echo "</span>"; //закрываем спан
    echo "</div>"; //закрываем див
}
```

Он выводит значения вот в таком виде:

```
<div class="year">
<div class="blok"><a href="/years/2017">2017</a><br><span>текст</span</div>
<div class="blok"><a href="/years/2016">2016</a><br><span>текст</span></div>
и т.д.
<div>
```

Как реализовать вывод, чтобы каждые 2 значения обворачивались в еще один див, например:

```
<div class="year">
<div class="new">
<div class="blok"><a href="/years/2017">2017</a><br><span>текст</span>   </div>
<div class="blok"><a href="/years/2016">2016</a><br><span>текст</span></div>
<div>
<div class="new">
<div class="blok"><a href="/years/2015">2015</a><br><span>текст</span></div>
<div class="blok"><a href="/years/2014">2014</a><br><span>текст</span></div>
<div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое не самое элегантное, но работающее решение, оно вставляется на этап вывода. Мы просто считаем сколько значений вывелось и если 2, то закрываем `<div>` и обнуляем счетчик

```php
$div_new = 0; //В самом начале файла объявите переменную

foreach($stack as $key => $count){  //выводим окончательный вариант

    if($div_new === 0){ //Если значение равно нулю открывает новый DIV
    echo '<div class="new">';
    }

    echo "<div class='blok'>"; //открываем див
    echo "<a href=/" . $xfield . "/";  //открываем ссылку
    echo $key; //подставляем значение для поиска
    echo ">";
    echo $key; //имя ссылки
    echo "</a>"; //закрываем ссылку
    echo "<br><span>";  //открываем спан
    echo declOfNum($count, array('год', 'года', 'годов'));//кол-во повторов со склонением
    echo "</span>"; //закрываем спан
    echo "</div>"; //закрываем див

    $div_new++; //Добавляем единицу
    if($div_new === 2){ //Прошло 2 значение, значит закрываем DIV и обнуляем счетчик
    echo '</div>';
    $div_new = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо за помощь!